# "attempted to call require with invalid arguments" How to Fix Roblox Studio Luau

Tags: roblox, luau

I was making an Egg-Open-Gui for a simulator and when I ran the script it always arrored this:

> Attempted to call require with invalid argument(s)
>
> > Script Players.Robloxgamer_73738.PlayerGui.Menu.EggScript

the so called "Eggscript" is local

here is my script:

```
wait(game.Loaded)
wait(5)

local petmodule = require(game:GetService("ServerScriptService"):FindFirstChild("PetModule"))

local cost = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Cost.Value

local player = game.Players.lo

local openOnceButton = script.Parent.OpenOnce
local autoOpenButton = script.Parent.AutoOpen



openOnceButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    if player.leaderstats[" Money "].Value >= cost then

        player.leaderstats[" Money "].Value = (player.leaderstats[" Money "].Value - cost)

        local pet = petmodule.chooseRandomPet()

        local petVal = Instance.new("StringValue")
        petVal.Name = pet.Name
        petVal.Parent = player.PetInventory

        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireServer(pet)

        print(pet.Name.." selected")

    end
    
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `ServerScriptService` in the client. It will be empty, thus, there will be no child. The `FindFirstChild` call will return `nil`, which is obviously invalid. Move the module to `ReplicatedStorage`.

Besides, you don't seem to understand [the client-server model](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/networking/client-server-model). You  can't really change a leaderstat value from the client; it will only affect the client and not the server, so other clients will be unaware of the change. You can use [`RemoteEvent`s](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/networking/remote-events-and-functions) but make sure that you structure them in a way that it will be safe.